# PHP: Create global function out of anonymous function

Tags: php, function, anonymous-function

I want to create **global** function with dynamic name, but I dont want to write code of function as string, as it's required in PHP docs about `create_function` function.

Dream scenario would be like:

```
$functionName = "new_super_function";
$functionBody = function($a,$b) { return $a + $b; };

if ( !function_exists($functionName) ) create_function($functionName, $functionBody);

//from here my function with dynamic name is ready
//I could now call it like call_user_func($functionName, 5, 7) => 12
//or just use it later like new_super_function(5,7) => 12
```

I was looking for such sort of possibility but I couldnt find anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Just assign the function body to the function name like this:

```
$functionName = "new_super_function";
$functionBody = function($a,$b) { return $a + $b; };

if (!function_exists($functionName))
    $functionName = $functionBody;

echo call_user_func($functionName, 5, 7);  //Same as: echo $functionName(5, 7);
```

output:

```
12
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to declare an anonymous function which you can also call in other function, this won't be possible, since it is assigned to a variable and the variable is in a scope, so you either have to pass the variable with the anonymous function as argument or use the `global` keyword.

Comment: Will it be global function with given name?

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak Since it is an anonymous function assigned to a variable no

Comment: Well, my point is to create global function with given name, I've edited question to point that

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak Why do you even want to do this? I think if you would have to create a function dynamically you have to rethink your code logic

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak Also this is not possible, since an anonymous function is assigned to a variable and the variable is in a scope, so you won't be able to call it in another function if you don't pass it as argument or use `global` keyword

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak updated my answer. This what you want won't be possible as long as you don't declare the function normally.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be fun to try to answer it. You would have to create your own `create_function` method.

```
function my_create_function($name, $callable) {
    $GLOBALS['my_functions'][$name] = $callable;

    $call_wrapper = sprintf('function %s() {
        $arguments = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func_array($GLOBALS["my_functions"][%s], $arguments);
    }', $name, $name);

    eval($call_wrapper);
}
```

Test:

```
class Test {
    static public function prepare() {
        $add_function = function($a, $b) { return $a + $b; };

        var_dump($add_function(1, 2));

        my_create_function('my_add', $add_function);
    }

    static public function testit() {
        var_dump(call_user_func('my_add', 1, 2));

        var_dump(call_user_func_array('my_add', array(1, 2)));

        var_dump(my_add(1, 2));
    }
}

Test::prepare();
Test::testit();
```